# Unable to add relationship because dtypes don't match in Featuretools

Tags: pandas, categorical-data, featuretools

The following error arises when trying to add a relationship between two entities in Featuretools

```
Unable to add relationship because ID in metadata is Pandas `dtype category` and ID in transactions is Pandas `dtype category`
```

Note, the Series are not necessarily the same `cat.Codes`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error arises because the categories are different between the categorical variables you are trying to relate. In the code example below, all 3 series are categoricals, but only `s` and `s2` have the same dtype.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.api.types import is_dtype_equal

s = pd.Series(["a","b","a"], dtype="category")
s2 = pd.Series(["b","b","a"], dtype="category")
s3 = pd.Series(["a","b","c"], dtype="category")

is_dtype_equal(s.dtype, s2.dtype) # this is True
is_dtype_equal(s.dtype, s3.dtype) # this is False
```

To fix this, you need update your dataframe before loading it into Featuretools to make sure the Pandas Categoricals have the same values category values. Here's how you do that

if `s` is missing categories from `s3`

```
new_s = s.astype(s3.dtype)
is_dtype_equal(new_s.dtype, s3.dtype) # this is True
```

if both Series are missing categories from the other we must make the union of the categories

```
s4 = pd.Series(["b","c"], dtype="category")

categories = set(s.dtype.categories + s4.dtype.categories) # make union of categories

new_s = s.astype("category", categories=categories)
new_s4 = s4.astype("category", categories=categories)

is_dtype_equal(new_s.dtype, new_s4.dtype) # this is True
```